Programatically refresh a table with Javascript that is connected through Ninja Tables to a google sheet
I have a google sheet that updates every 5 minutes with new information. That google sheet is displayed through Ninja Tables onto a website. I'm trying to make a function in javascript that updates the new values every 5 minutes.
What I tried so far is
function run() {
 
    / 
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
     
    let url = 'https://docs.google.com';//i took out the complete link
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    
    var element = document.getElementById('footable_130431');
    if(element != null){
        console.log("element not null");
    }
 
    // function execute after request is successful 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            element.innerhtml = this.responseText;
         
        }
        
    }
    // Sending our request 
    xhr.send();
}

setInterval(run, 30000);

but it didn't work. I also tried getting the element by referring to the DOM object per ninja tables' instructions of $table. It seems changing the innerhtml in this way doesn't do anything, or if it does I don't quite know what it does because I tried changing it to "hello" and I didn't see it. Granted the table I refer to is massive and complicated so maybe it showed somewhere that I didn't see
I also tried
function reload(){
    var container = document.getElementById("footable_130431");
    var content = container.innerHTML;
    container.innerHTML= content; 
    
   //this line is to watch the result in console , you can remove it later  
    console.log("Refreshed"); 
}

setInterval(reload, 30000);

And not only did it not work but it broke the interface of the table
Edit: I've since determined that I can in fact edit the contents of the element with innerhtml, I must just not know exactly how it works

Dumb question but is the document public ? Also XMLHttpRequest wont work bcs of CORS. Also element.innerhtml should be element.innerHTML. Try with fetch ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch or https://developers.google.com/docs/api/samples/output-json#javascript

No, the document I'm using isn't for public use. Oh, wow I can't believe that capitalization matters. And thanks I'll try that

If its not public then you should use google api for that i think.. just test with random public file to be sure.

Yeah it actually started working once I used the proper capitalization, but it screwed up the formatting of the table, with the API would I be able to take the data and insert it into the existing table?
